# How to Change current date format to day name?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the subtract date format by this javascript code but i want it should print day name for example "Sunday". currently it's printing Wed "Jan 30 2019 02:31:30 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)"

```js
var el_up = document.getElementById("GFG_UP");
var el_down = document.getElementById("GFG_DOWN");
var today = new Date();
el_up.innerHTML = "Today's date = " + today;

Date.prototype.subtractDays = function(d) {
  this.setTime(this.getTime() - (d * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  return this;
}

function gfg_Run() {
  var a = new Date();
  a.subtractDays(4);
  el_down.innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="color:green;">
  GeeksForGeeks
</h1>

<p id="GFG_UP" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">
</p>

<button onclick="gfg_Run()"> 
       subtractDays 
      </button>

<p id="GFG_DOWN" style="color:green; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
</p>
```

How can I convert it?

Comment: Simply run `.getDay();` on `new Date()` to get the day. Like this: `new Date().getDay();` Then simply map the day number to an array of the weekdays

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mufasa

here is the map of the day number 

`function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date();
  var weekday = new Array(7);
  weekday[0] = "Sunday";
  weekday[1] = "Monday";
  weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
  weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
  weekday[4] = "Thursday";
  weekday[5] = "Friday";
  weekday[6] = "Saturday";

  var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}`

but subtract is not working. would you pls show me how subtract work. i wand 4 days Subtract

Thanks

Comment: I found a way...
`
<p id="shippingSixDay"></p>

<script>

function getWeekDay(date){
    var weekdays = new Array(
        "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
    );
    var day = date.getDay();
    return weekdays[day];
}

var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
var weekDay = getWeekDay(tomorrow);
console.log('Tomorrow will be a ' + weekDay);
  var weekDay = getWeekDay(tomorrow);
  document.getElementById("shippingSixDay").innerHTML = weekDay;

</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the day with [getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) method. You will get the day as number, so if you want to get the name you should compare it to an array.

Example:

```js
const d = new Date();
const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
console.log(days[d.getDay()]);
```